# post the last 25 lines of a .txt file to a website?

Tags: php, html, database, text-files

I've got a form uploading input lines of text to a .txt file and would like to display the last 25 lines of the text file on the page with the text entry form (I'd also like to give each line a random left margin value between 1-800px) - how can I achieve it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will want to check out [file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), and [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

Perhaps something like:

```
$output = "";
$lines = array_slice(file("test.txt"), -25, 25);

foreach ( $lines as $line )
{
    $output .= '<div style="margin-left: ' . rand(1, 800) . 'px;">' . $line . '</div>';
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: I tried putting that in a php wrap but it doesn't seem to work for me, am I just being dim?

Comment: My bad, I didn't test it first... updated the code and tested, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well you either have to read in the whole file as an array of lines, pick the last 25 or use the shell command `tail -n 25`. Then output them in `<p>` tags with random `margin-left` styles.

Answer (score 0):

- First call [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read file's content in an array
- Then call [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to read last 25 lines from that array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix-y server then `$lines = array(); $result = exec("tail -25 $filename", $lines)` should give you what you need. The output is likely to involve a `foreach($lines as $line) { ... }` and inline CSS such as `echo '<p style="margin-left:' . rand(1, 800) . 'px;">' . $line . '</p>'.`

Comment: If you do this, make sure $filename is secure.